# Powershell: FTP download not working despite having permissions

Tags: powershell, server, ftp

I am trying to download files from another company's server using the specs they provided and bring them to my local folder but its not working.
I tested just being able to list the directory and that works.

```
# Function to get directory listing 
Function Get-FTPFileList { 

Param (
 [System.Uri]$server,
 [string]$username,
 [string]$password,
 [string]$directory

)

try 
 {
    #Create URI by joining server name and directory path
    $uri =  "$server$directory" 

    #Create an instance of FtpWebRequest
    $FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($uri)
    
    #Set the username and password credentials for authentication
    $FTPRequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
   
    #Set method to ListDirectoryDetails to get full list
    #For short listing change ListDirectoryDetails to ListDirectory
    $FTPRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectoryDetails
    
    #Get FTP response
    $FTPResponse = $FTPRequest.GetResponse() 
    
    #Get Reponse data stream
    $ResponseStream = $FTPResponse.GetResponseStream()
    
    #Read data Stream
    $StreamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $ResponseStream  
   
    #Read each line of the stream and add it to an array list
    $files = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    While ($file = $StreamReader.ReadLine())
     {
        #Get-Content $file.FullName
       [void] $files.add("$file")
      
    }

}
catch {
    #Show error message if any
    write-host -message $_.Exception.InnerException.Message
}

    #Close the stream and response
    $StreamReader.close()
    $ResponseStream.close()
    $FTPResponse.Close()

    Return $files


}

#Set server name, user, password and directory
$server = 'ftp://1.1.1.1/' #Cant show the real one
$username = 'username'
$password = 'pswd'
$directory ='folderpath/*.810OUT'

#Function call to get directory listing
$filelist = Get-FTPFileList -server $server -username $username -password $password -directory $directory

#Write output
Write-Output $filelist
```

This works and through FileZilla I saw I full permissoin on the folder and subequently the files within it.

But then when I try the following:

```
$sourceuri = 'ftp://1.1.1.1//Orders/OutboxFolder/*.810OUT'
$targetpath = "C:\Users\myname\Downloads\test"
$username = "username"
$password = "pswd"

# Create a FTPWebRequest object to handle the connection to the ftp server
$ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::create($sourceuri)

# set the request's network credentials for an authenticated connection
$ftprequest.Credentials =
New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)

$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DownloadFile
$ftprequest.UseBinary = $true
$ftprequest.KeepAlive = $false

# send the ftp request to the server

$ftpresponse = $ftprequest.GetResponse()

# get a download stream from the server response
$responsestream = $ftpresponse.GetResponseStream()

# create the target file on the local system and the download buffer
$targetfile = New-Object IO.FileStream ($targetpath,[IO.FileMode]::Create)
[byte[]]$readbuffer = New-Object byte[] 1024

# loop through the download stream and send the data to the target file
do{
    $readlength = $responsestream.Read($readbuffer,0,1024)
    $targetfile.Write($readbuffer,0,$readlength)
}
while ($readlength -ne 0)

$targetfile.close()
```

It doesnt work.
I get these errors

```
Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."
At line:18 char:1
+ $ftpresponse = $ftprequest.GetResponse()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
 
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Access to the path 'C:\Users\myname\Downloads\test' is denied."
At line:24 char:15
+ ... argetfile = New-Object IO.FileStream ($targetpath,[IO.FileMode]::Crea ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I am new to trying to do this with Powershell so I am not sure what to do.
Also the port isn't used here by the specs given specify Port 21. And note that I don't want to recursively download. Just wants in that one location.

Comment: I don't think you can use _wildcards_ in FTP URIs, so `ftp://1.1.1.1//Orders/OutboxFolder/*.810OUT` won't work. The second error message suggests that `C:\Users\myname\Downloads\test` is an existing _directory_.

Comment: But in the first method since I wanted to just list everything, the wildcard did work. But how about this, what if i use the first method to get an array of each filename then use the second to specify each file?

Comment: @MilanPatel, sounds promising; it sounds like wildcards work with the `[System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectoryDetails` method, but not with `[System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DownloadFile`